# Button to run code only on this row in access report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report which is a list of players in a football team.  I want to add a button to the details so that when the button is clicked the fields in that row toggle between yellow and the normal background.

With my current code if I click on any of the buttons then all of the fields on all rows toggle.  I think what is happening is that the button itself isn't being distinct to the row

```
    Private Sub cmdToggle_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
Const BackgroundColour = 16777215
If PlayerName.BackColor = BackgroundColour Then
    PlayerName.BackColor = vbYellow
    Paid.BackColor = vbYellow
    PaymentNotes.BackColor = vbYellow
Else
    PlayerName.BackColor = BackgroundColour
    Paid.BackColor = BackgroundColour
    PaymentNotes.BackColor = BackgroundColour
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at this single function. I believe you have your code constructed correctly. My guess is that all of your text boxes are named "PlayerName", "Paid", or "PaymentNotes" rather than unique names like "PlayerName1, PlayerName2, and so on. If that is true then your code will change the backcolor for every box with the name "PlayerName"

Comment: Thanks Trevor.  I get what you are saying but what I don't understand is that the "rows" are formed during runtime by access - maybe this is where the issue sits as then each record isn't seen discreetly?  I was hoping for something like CurrentRecord.PlayerName to be the answer but I have played about with everything I can think it might be but feel as though I'm missing the collection name to unlock things for me.